# Different sampling rates for half and full channels on oscilloscope? How is it done?

Tags: adc, oscilloscope

In the documentation for the [Keysight DSOX1204G](https://www.keysight.com/en/pdx-2969966-pn-DSOX1204G/oscilloscope-70-100-200-mhz-4-analog-channels?nid=-56007.5128019&cc=US&lc=eng), it has the interesting note for the sampling rate of:

```
2 GSa/s (half channels)
1 GSa/s (all channels)
```

So, if I use all 4 channels on the scope, I get GSa/s, and if I use only two channels I get 2 GSa/s.  I would assume at the core of the scope there's some low resolution ADC with a convert line that is tied to a 1GHz signal.  For the 2 GSa/s are they just tying two ADCs together at the inputs but putting the convert lines 180 degrees out of phase, or is it something more interesting?

Comment: Yes, current scopes work by having multiple slower rate ADCs (with fast analog bandwidth) which can cooperate to take samples at a higher rate for a given channel, or be assigned to different channels.  For a given model (cost) you can operate it to maximize speed or channels, or you buy a different more expensive model with a different product of rate * channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel from Keysight here - this is a very common behavior for this range of oscilloscope. Essentially, manufacturers (like us) build out acquisition boards to handle two channels at a time.

So, a four channel scope has two acquisition boards*. When you use two channels on the same board, the ADC has to cut its sampling in half. It spends 50% on one channel and 50% on the other.

If you'd like to dig in more, I highly recommend this talk given by one of our ADC designers:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzHyxysSubUmxGOMVpiKLxouweh2AAlG1

**Acquisition systems would be more accurate, as it's often just one PCB. However, each "path" will have chips/ASICs/ADCs/processors that handle two signals per chip.*

Comment: That seems to be it.  I was just hoping for something more interesting.

Comment: Nope, sorry! Time domain interleaving :)